# Tag text using grep and paste in r

Tags: r, dataframe, text, text-mining, data-manipulation

I have two data frames. The first one:

```
keyword <- c("apple","peach","grape","berry","kiwi fruit")
keyword <- data.frame(keyword)
```

[image]

The second one:

```
sentence <- c("I like apple","I hate apple","grape is good")
url <- c("url1","url2","url3")
sentence <- data.frame(sentence,url)
```

[image]

What I need to is: if keyword is contained in sentence, paste url to the text. If multiple sentences contain the keyword, paste all url. The final result is like:

[image]

I tried to use the code as bellow, but it did not work out as expected.

```
keyword$Label <- character(length(keyword$keyword))

for (i in 1:length(keyword$keyword)) {
keyword$Label[grep(keyword$keyword[i],sentence$sentence)] <- sentence$url
}
```

Comment: Do you need help to understand HOW this should be done? (code-wise) Or do you want to know WHAT should be done? (concept-wise)

I would suggest to make something like a conditional join... (concept wise)

Comment: I need the code-wise solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `stringr` + `dplyr` + `tidyr`:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

sentence %>%
  mutate(sentence = str_extract(sentence, paste0(keyword$keyword, collapse = "|"))) %>%
  right_join(keyword, by = c("sentence" = "keyword")) %>%
  group_by(sentence) %>%
  mutate(URL = 1:n()) %>%
  spread(URL, url, sep = "") %>%
  rename(keyword = sentence)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   keyword [5]
     keyword  URL1  URL2
*      <chr> <chr> <chr>
1      apple  url1  url2
2      berry  <NA>  <NA>
3      grape  url3  <NA>
4 kiwi fruit  <NA>  <NA>
5      peach  <NA>  <NA>
```

**Data:**

```
keyword <- c("apple","peach","grape","berry","kiwi fruit")
keyword <- data.frame(keyword, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
sentence <- c("I like apple","I hate apple","grape is good")
url <- c("url1","url2","url3")
sentence <- data.frame(sentence,url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```